# BigQuery: Find the most common combination of 2 values

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a dataset like this:

| person# | fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | orange |
| 001 | grapes |
| 001 | apple |
| 002 | orange |
| 002 | apple |
| 003 | orange |
| 003 | grapes |
| 004 | orange |
| 004 | apple |

This is the output I am expecting:

| **combination | unique_person_count |
| --- | --- |
| apple, orange | 3 |
| orange, grapes | 2 |
| apple, grapes | 1 |

Please provide your much appreciated help in BiqQuery as this is being done in GCP.

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far and explain the specific issue you are facing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try below simple approach

```
select 
  format('%s, %s', a.fruit, b.fruit) combination, 
  count(distinct a.person) unique_person_count
from your_table a
join your_table b
on a.person = b.person
and a.fruit < b.fruit
group by combination
order by unique_person_count desc
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]